# Bing Visual Search C# SDK returns an empty response

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, bing-api

I'm trying to make a simple tool that uses the Bing Visual Search API thingy. I'm following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-visual-search/visual-search-sdk-c-sharp#client) to set up the SDK, but the API response seems to be pretty much empty no matter which image I pass to that Search method:

```
var ms = await DownloadStream(img);
var res = await client.Images.VisualSearchMethodAsync(image: ms, knowledgeRequest: (string)null);
```

I also thought it might be caused by the auth not being correct, but it seems to return 200, so I'm not sure anymore.

The response body only shows the basic stuff and one empty tag:

```
{"_type": "ImageKnowledge", "instrumentation": {"_type": "ResponseInstrumentation"}, "tags": [{"displayName": "", "actions": [{"actionType": "MoreSizes"}, {"actionType": "ImageById"}]}], "image": {"imageInsightsToken": ""}}
```

I'm using that 7 day trial subscription and I tried authenticating with both keys it gave me.

Am I missing something here?

## Edit:

Here's the download function. It downloads .png attachments from Discord links:

```
static async Task<MemoryStream> DownloadStream(string url)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (var http = new HttpClient())
    using (var res = await http.GetAsync(url))
        if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await res.Content.CopyToAsync(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
        }
    return ms;
}
```

An example of a link: [https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/462686437331042306/462987122203295754/61A88kq3rJL.*SY355*.jpg](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/462686437331042306/462987122203295754/61A88kq3rJL._SY355_.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in thinking that authentication isn't an issue, because you're getting some sort of JSON response--it would be a 401 error otherwise. This empty response happens when there's a problem with your file format and the API doesn't recognize that the stream you're passing in is an image. (If you uploaded a .txt file you would get this same empty response.)

If you post the code to your DownloadStream function, we might be able to help you debug further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited my question and included the download method.

Comment: You can actually use the URL directly in the Visual Search request, without having to download the image! [Here's an example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-dotnet-sdk-samples/blob/master/BingSearchv7/BingVisualSearch/VisualSearchSamples.cs#L151) of using a URL to send a request.

Comment: With your current code, the problem may be that the MemoryStream is just a stream of bytes and the data might not contain the required file type information. [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/psSdkJson6/src/SDKs/CognitiveServices/dataPlane/Search/BingVisualSearch/BingVisualSearch/Generated/Images.cs#L326) is where the SDK attempts to convert the image to a FileStream.